# Conditional scheduling on Airflow

Tags: airflow, scheduling, sensors

I have two DAGs with different schedules on Airflow, `DAG1` creates a table on Redshift every hour, `DAG2` is a process that runs daily and needs to read the table created by `DAG1`. I'm facing an issue where if `DAG2` takes longer than usual then `DAG1` starts running giving me concurrent connection issues on Redshift.

Is there any way to setup a sensor in `DAG1` to check if `DAG2` is running and in that case to wait for it to finish before continuing?

I tried using ExternalTaskSensor but it only checks if the last run of the DAG was successful and not if the DAG is running. Or am I wrong?

Is there any way to get the status of a DAG and use that to reschedule another DAG?

Answer (score 0):

You can let the task of `DAG2` fail and start again after 10 minutes, or any other reasonable duration you know `DAG1` will probably finish.

The following setup makes your task retry every 10 minutes, for 6 times, so if your hourly job (`DAG1`) is not taking more than approximately one hour, this should work just fine.
Add this to your `DAG2` at the `default_args` section:

```
default_args = {
    ...
    # Your default_args
    ...
    'retries': 6,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=10)
}
```

Be careful not to write these properties twice, if `retries` or `retry_delay` already exists in `DAG2`, override them.